# Links to blog posts on Archive page (not Wordpress)

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I've created a blog site that (for now) is strictly written in HTML and CSS.  On the Home page I'd like to be able to create links to additional blog articles on the Archive page - not just links to the Archive page but to specific blog articles but I'm not sure how to do that.  Any help appreciated  Thanks.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken couldn't you just use an HREF link that points to the URL where your additional blog article exists? If thats not the case could you clarify what you are asking for and perhaps provide some code or a URL were your site exists so people could better help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use an href as suggested above like so

```
<a href="your_blog_post.html">That Posts Title </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="/URL_TO_SPECIFIC_ARCHIVE_PAGE.html">Archive post title</a>
```

Comment: Yes, I understand how to create the link to the archive page.  But unless I create separate archive pages for each individual entry, the visitor will be directed to the start of the archive page, not to that particular entry.  So in my text editor do I create separate files and effectively separate pages for each entry?  How will that impact loading the site?

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have server-side software, I think I've figured out a work-around without having to create multiple pages.  I will give the title of each blog entry a unique id attribute.  Then the links will simply be Title of Entry.  I think this should work without having to create a multitude of pages.